# Fastest method of checking if multiple different strings are a substring of a 2nd string

Tags: substring, match

**Context:**
I'm creating a program which will sort and rename my media files which are named e.g. `The.Office.s04e03.DIVX.WaREZKiNG.avi` into an organized folder structure, which will consist of a list of folders for each TV Series, each folder will have a list of folders for the seasons, and those folders will contain the media files.

**The problem:**
I am unsure as to what the best method for reading a file name and determining what part of that name is the TV Show. For e.g. In `"The.Office.s04e03.DIVX.WaREZKiNG.avi"`, The Office is the name of the series. I decided to have a list of all TV Shows and to check if each TV Show is a substring in the file name, but as far as I know this means I have to check every single series against the name for every file.

**My question**: How should I determine if a string contains one of many other strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Aho-Corsasick algorithm[1] efficiently solves the "does this possibly long string exactly  contain any of these many short strings" problem.

However, I suspect this isn't really the problem you want to solve.  It seems to me that you want something to extract the likely components from a string that is in one of possibly many different formats.  I suspect that having a few different regexps for likely providers, video formats, season/episode markers, perhaps a database of show names, etc, is really what you want.  Then you can independently run these different 'information extractors' on your filenames to pull out their structure.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the overall structure of the filenames in general, for instance is the series name always first? If so a tree structure work well. Is there a standard marking between words (period in your example) if so you can split the string on those and create a case-insensitive hashtable of interesting words to boost performance.

However extracting seasons and episodes becomes more difficult, a simple solution would be to implement an algorithm to handle each format you uncover, although by using hints you could create an interesting parser if you wanted too. (Likely overkill however)